# Scrape .xml file for images and mirror directories wget/grep/curl(?)

Tags: xml, macos, curl, grep, wget

How could I scrape an xml file (Wordpress Export) for all images and then save them locally, mirroring their directory?

E.g save `<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/image.jpg"/>` to a folder on my Mac `Desktop/ScrapedImages/wp-content/uploads/2015/image.jpg`

It's important to retain their directory.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: any decent programming language or scripting language would be fully capable of doing this, do you know any programming language whatsoever?

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this, genuine question that has nearly been answered.

Answer (score 0):

any decent programming/scripting language language would be fully capable of doing this, do you know any programming language whatsoever?

here's an example with PHP:

```
<?php
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile("export.xml");
foreach($domd->getElementsByTagName("img") as $img){
    $src=$img->getAttribute("src");
    if(empty($src)){
        continue;
    }
    $path=parse_url($src,PHP_URL_PATH);
    if(!is_dir('.'.dirname($path)))
        mkdir('.'.dirname($path).'/', 0777, TRUE);
    file_put_contents('.'.$path,file_get_contents($src));
}
```

none of the tools you tagged are capable of this by themselves (although wget's mirror functionality gets close, but you'd need a web server to serve it to wget first. and a clever grep regex could also get close, but about as buggy as parsing html with regex ever is)

(also note, the code above was not optimized for ram usage, it will put the entire file in ram before flushing it to disk, so if you had 4GB ram, and no swap, and tried to download a 5GB image this way, you'd get an OOM crash. can easily be mitigated with an fread/fwrite loop)

edit: here is a function you can use to replace file_get_contents if you have `allow_url_fopen=Off` in php:

```
function curl_get_contents(string $url): string {
    try {
        $ch = curl_init ();
        if (! $ch) {
            throw new \RuntimeException ( 'curl_init failed!' );
        }
        if (! curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true 
        ) )) {
            throw new \RuntimeException ( 'curl_setopt_array failed! errno: ' . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ". error: " . curl_error ( $ch ) );
        }
        $ret = curl_exec ( $ch );
        if (! is_string ( $ret )) {
            throw new \RuntimeException ( 'curl_exec failed! errno: ' . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ". error: " . curl_error ( $ch ) );
        }
        return $ret;
    } finally{
        curl_close ( $ch );
    }
}
```

(going by your comments, you have that problem)

Comment: Thanks for this, I've given it a go and it seems to mirror the directories, but the images are all 0kb in filesize.

Comment: @Mark oh, you probably have `allow_url_fopen=Off` in php.ini then, i added an alternative fetch function using curl, try that

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting any results from that option, just a blank screen. `$url = 'gw-news-export.xml';` is correct to set the URL for the xml file?

Comment: P.S. my phpinfo is saying allow_url_fopen=On